# Hot Reload builds once but hot restart builds twice

Tags: flutter, dart

So I know hot reload keeps the preserved state whereas hot restart doesn't. and that's why it shows "**3**" in output. But I can't get why does the build function run twice in case of hot restart but only once in hot reload.

Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

int cnt = 0;
class Loading extends StatefulWidget {
  const Loading({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Loading> createState() => _LoadingState();
}

class _LoadingState extends State<Loading> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('count: ');
    print(++cnt);
    return const Scaffold(
      body: Text('loading screen'),
    );
  }
}
```

[Hot Restart output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0ZnI.png)

[Hot Reload output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zV6Dy.png)

I was analyzing the behavior of hot reload and hot restart.

Comment: can you include your code as text, not screenshots?

Comment: why would you worry about this? `build` method can be called by a framework multiple times and your code must not depend on that number

Comment: Your links are incorrect, however I would surmise that a widget higher in the widget tree is being rebuilt twice and causing your widget to be build twice also.